# Should I spray or fertilize my crops?

Tags: farming-simulator-2015

I'm playing Farming Simulator 2015 and trying to decide whether I should spray or fertilize my crops. What is the difference between fertilizing and spraying? Does one give a bigger yield than the other or is it just the looks that are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **To quote the** [***Farming Simulator Wiki***](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/)**, concerning [Liquid Fertilizer Effectiveness and Economy](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/wiki/Liquid_Fertilizer_(Farming_Simulator_15))**
>
> Liquid Fertilizer is not a cheap option, but requires virtually no infrastructure and little equipment. Unfortunately, **due to problems and bugs with the base game's content, Liquid Fertilizer does not provide any advantages over Solid Fertilizer**, and actually has a few disadvantages - making Solid Fertilizer the preferred option.

[Fertilizer Spreaders](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/wiki/Fertilizer_Spreaders_(Farming_Simulator_15)) use [solid fertilizer](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/wiki/Liquid_Fertilizer_(Farming_Simulator_15)), while the [Fertilizer Sprayer](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/wiki/Fertilizer_Sprayers_(Farming_Simulator_15)) uses [liquid fertilizer](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/wiki/Liquid_Fertilizer_(Farming_Simulator_15)). There appears to be no difference, in regards to the effect it has on the crops.

However, liquid fertilizer can be spread over a wider area, and can therefore allow you to fertilize your crops quicker. This comes at the cost of having a larger vehicle to move, and can be counterproductive, if the field is not of basic shape, and without obstacles.

It is worth considering the advantages and disadvantages of this benefit, in the early game, as the [Farming Simulator Wiki](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/) suggests solid fertiliser to be more cost effective, and efficient.